# ECS CapacityProvider not Scaling in

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-auto-scaling

According to the docs, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cluster-auto-scaling.html#update-ecs-resources-cas
[image]
Looking at the services, I have 3 services.
2 Replicas are both running on a single host and a DAEMON is on both hosts. So per the docs, the scale in protection should've been removed, and the error mentioned in the 2nd image below shouldn't have come.

I am facing the exact issue as [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72444890/aws-autoscaling-group-managed-by-ecs-cluster-capacity-provider-cannot-scale-in-d) but that is still unanswered.

Current Capacity Provider state:
[image]

Error in ASG:
[image]

Service definitions:

[image]

2 Replicas + 1 DAEMON in the first instance (first three tasks)
1 DAEMON in the second instance should've been removed due to scale-in, but it isn't.

[image]

Capacity Provider configuration:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, this was because `AmazonECSManaged` tag was missing in the ASG. After adding `AmazonECSManaged=true`, the cluster was able to scale-in

[image]

[image]